# How can I add multiple labels on amcharts4 value axis?

Tags: amcharts4

I need to add more labels on the value axis ,like
[value axis labeld needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqzJm.png)
My code shared in here , minGridDistance doesn't seem to be working

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
"category": "Research & Development",
"value": 0.015
}, {
"category": "Marketing",
"value": 0.25
}, {
"category": "Distribution",
"value": 916
}];

```
// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;
valueAxis.logarithmic = true;

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
series.name = "Sales";
```

https://codepen.io/lak2022/pen/BaYWEKX

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `axisRanges`. Here is a dirty example:

```js
var breaksValues = [0.015, 0.1, 0.15, 1, 1.5, 10, 15];
var breaksLabels = [0.015, 0.1, 0.15, 1, 1.5, 10, 15];
for(var i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
  var range = valueAxis.axisRanges.create();
  range.value = breaksValues[i];
  range.label.text = breaksLabels[i];
}
```

[image]